# Generating rolling z-scores of panel data in Stata

Tags: stata

I have an unbalanced panel data set (countries and years). For simplicity let's say I have one variable, x, that I am measuring. The panel data sorted first by country (a 3-digit numeric country-code) and then by year. I would like to write a .do file that generates a new variable, z_x, containing the standardized values of the variable x. The variables should be standardized by subtracting the mean from the preceding (exclusive) m time periods, and then dividing by the standard deviation from those same time periods. If this is not possible, return a missing value.

Currently, the code I am using to accomplish this is the following (**edited now for clarity**)

```
xtset weocountrycode year
sort weocountrycode year

local win_len = 5 // Defining rolling window length.

quietly: rolling sd_x=r(sd) mean_x=r(mean), window(`win_len') saving(stats_x, replace): sum x 
use stats_x, clear
rename end year
save, replace
use all_data_PROCESSED_FINAL.dta, clear
quietly: merge 1:1 (weocountrycode year) using stats_x  
replace sd_x = . if `x'[_n-`win_len'+1] == . | weocountrycode[_n-`win_len'+1] !=  weocountrycode[_n] // This and next line are for deleting values that rolling calculates when I actually want missing values. 
replace mean_`x' = . if `x'[_n-`win_len'+1] == . | weocountrycode[_n-`win_len'+1] != weocountrycode[_n]
gen z_`x' = (`x' - mean_`x'[_n-1])/sd_`x'[_n-1] // calculate z-score
```

**UPDATE:**

My struggle with rolling is that when rolling is set up to use a window length 5 rolling mean, it automatically does window length 1,2,3,4 means for the first, second, third and fourth entries (when there are not 5 preceding entries available to average out). In fact, it does this in general - if the first non-missing value is on entry 5, it will do a length 1 rolling average on entry 5, length 2 rolling average on entry 6, ..... and then finally start doing length 5 moving averages on entry 9. My issue is that I do not want this, so I would like to avoid performing these calculations. Until now, I have only been able to figure out how to delete them after they are done, which is both inefficient and bothersome.

I tried adding an if clause to the -rolling- statement:

```
quietly: rolling sd_x=r(sd) mean_x=r(mean) if x[_n-`win_len'+1] != . & weocountrycode[_n-`win_len'+1] != weocountrycode[_n], window(`win_len') saving(stats_x, replace): sum x
```

But it did not fix the problem and the output is "weird" in the sense that

1) If `win_len' is equal to, say, 10, there are 15 missing values in the resulting z_x variable, instead of 9.
2) Even though there are "extra" missing values in z_x, the observations **still** start out as window length 1 means, then window length 2 means, etc. which makes no sense to me.

Which leads me to believe I fundamentally don't understand 1) what -rolling- is doing and 2) how an if clause works in the context of -rolling-.

Does this help?

Thanks!

Comment: In fact, too much detail here for my taste. Can you isolate in a single sentence what `rolling` doesn't do that you want or does do that you don't want?

Comment: Updated above. In a single sentence: rolling tries to do an average when it can't really do what I asked it to; I would rather it just return a missing value when the data is not available, but instead it just tries to work what it has available.

Comment: If you save the results of `r(N)` after `summarize` you can `replace` other results based on incomplete windows by missing.

Comment: So, no way to have rolling simply not calculate these values? It's wasting a lot of time and printing a whole lot of e's.

Comment: You could prefix `rolling` with `quietly` or use the `nodots` option to suppress display. Can you quantify extra computation time compared with your time spent trying to fix what you don't like?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand completely but I'll try to answer based on what I think your problem is, and based on a comment by @NickCox.

You say:

> ... when rolling is set up to use a window length 5 rolling mean...
>   if the first non-missing value is
>   on entry 5, it will do a length 1 rolling average on entry 5, length 2
>   rolling average on entry 6, ...

This is expected. `help rolling` states:

> The window size refers to calendar periods, not the number of
>   observations.  If there
>           are missing data (for example, because of weekends), the actual number of observations used by command may be less than
>   window(#).

It's not actually doing a "length 1 rolling average", but I get to that later.
Below some examples to see what `rolling` does:

```
clear all
set more off

*-------------------------- example data -----------------------------

set obs 92

gen dat = _n - 1
format dat %tq

egen seq = fill(1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2)

tsset dat

tempfile main
save "`main'"

list in 1/12, separator(4)


*------------------- Example 1. None missing ------------------------

rolling mean=r(mean), window(4) stepsize(4) clear: summarize seq, detail
list in 1/12, separator(0)


*------- Example 2. All but one value, missing in first window ------

use "`main'", clear
replace seq = . in 1/3
list in 1/8

rolling mean=r(mean), window(4) stepsize(4) clear: summarize seq, detail
list in 1/12, separator(0)


*------------- Example 3. All missing in first window --------------

use "`main'", clear
replace seq = . in 1/4
list in 1/8

rolling mean=r(mean), window(4) stepsize(4) clear: summarize seq, detail
list in 1/12, separator(0)
```

Note I use the `stepsize` option to make things much easier to follow. Because the date variable is in quarters, I set `windowsize(4)` and `stepsize(4)` so `rolling` is just computing averages by year. I hope that's easy to see.

- *Example 1* does as expected. No problem here.
- *Example 2* on the other hand, should be more interesting for you. We've said that what matters are **calendar periods**, so the mean is computed for the whole year (four quarters), even though it contains missings. There are three missings and one non-missing. `summarize` is computing the mean over the whole year, but `summarize` ignores missings, so it just outputs the mean of non-missings, which in this case is just one value.
- *Example 3* has missings for all four quarters of the year. Therefore, `summarize` outputs `.` (missing).

Your problem, as I understand it, is that when you face a situation like *Example 2*, you'd like the output to be missing. This is where I think Nick Cox's advice comes in. You could try something like:

```
rolling mean=r(mean) N=r(N), window(4) stepsize(4) clear: summarize seq, detail
replace mean = . if N != 4
list in 1/12, separator(0)
```

This says: if the number of non-missings for the window (`r(N)`, also computed by `summarize`), is not the same as the window size, then replace it with missing.

Comment: You got my point nicely. BTW, if all you want from `summarize` is count and mean, then you don't need the `detail` option; on the contrary, you can apply `meanonly`. OP wants SD too, so this is irrelevant to the main question here.

Comment: Great, thanks for the responses. The above method is still calculating all of the values to be later replaced by missing values. Does anyone know if there is a way to avoid this? It seems wasteful, and the red letter "e"s that Stata prints to the console are bothersome.

Comment: You're welcome. Like I said, `summarize` is just ignoring the missings. That's the way it works. That makes more sense than to output a missing when there are non-missing values. The use of `replace` does not seem here a strong-enough argument to qualify the strategy as wasteful.